# Hadoop namenode daemon silently stops after 5 seconds

Tags: hadoop

I am relatively new to the wonders of Hadoop, but I am trying to manually build a cluster using the official Apache Hadoop documentation for Hadoop version 2.7.2. When I run the command: `$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode` I am returned to my console with a message stating that the daemon is starting, and the location of the .out file. When I vim to that file path, I am met with:

```
ulimit -a for user hadoop
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15017
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Running the start namenode command again will give me the same message that the daemon is starting and the location of the log file (same location).

Here is what I get when I look at the .log file:

```
2016-02-03 16:03:04,092 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = namenode_dns_name/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.7.2
```

What I know so far is that:

- Syntax errors in my configuration files will result in an error at the top of the log file
- My namenode daemon is silently crashing roughly 5 seconds after being started
- Improper settings in my configuration files can result in the namenode daemon silently crashing
- I do not have this jps command that I've seen mentioned in other questions

I do not know if this is an issue with my version of java, but I have tried using openjdk-1.8.0.65-3, and openjdk-1.7.0.95 (neither of which are listed on the official Hadoop Java Versions page here http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopJavaVersions, but I'm hoping I'm not restricted to only those versions)

I also do not know if it is an issue with my configuration files, but I will include them here for review (albeit with host names blocked out). And can list any other information necessary for debugging. As an aside, I am attempting to run both the namenode daemon and resourcemanager daemon on the same machine for testing purposes.

Thank you for your time.

hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.2/hdfs/namenode</value>
        <description>Path on the local filesystem where the NameNode stores the namespace and transaction logs persistently.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.hosts</name>
        <value>datanode_dns_name</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
        <value>268435456</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.handler.count</name>
        <value>100</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://namenode_dns_name</value>
        <description>NameNode URI</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
        <value>131072</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.admin.acl</name>
        <value> </value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.host</name>
        <value>namenode_dns_name</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>128</value>
        <description>Minimum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>2048</value>
        <description>Maximum limit of memory to allocate to each container request at the Resource Manager.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
        <description>The minimum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests lower than this won't take effect, and the specified value will get allocated the minimum.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>2</value>
        <description>The maximum allocation for every container request at the RM, in terms of virtual CPU cores. Requests higher than this won't take effect, and will get capped to this value.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>4096</value>
        <description>Physical memory, in MB, to be made available to running containers</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>4</value>
        <description>Number of CPU cores that can be allocated for containers.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you post namenode logs

Comment: @Krishna Added contents of .log file under the .out file contents.

Comment: Add complete log... Otherwise no use

Comment: @Krishna My apologies, I thought all the '@' were unusual but I didn't realize it was the editor hiding additional content due to string length. Turns out it threw a non Bind IOException and there appears to be a lot of questions already asked on this site and others regarding such issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log file indicated that the process threw a non Bind IOException due to the desired port being already taken. I now can also add to my list of known things that an '@' in vim indicates that a single line string exceeds the line size and is not the end of the file.